# installing Oracle Instant Client 10.2 on Solaris

Tags: oracle, solaris, sqlplus

we are trying to install Oracle Instant Client 10.2.0.2 for Solaris x86-64 in order to connect to an Oracle database on another server.

I downloaded and unzipped the required files into an /apps/oracle/instantclient_10_2 directory:

- instantclient-basic-hpux-ia64-32-10.2.0.2-20060428.zip
- instantclient-sdk-hpux-ia64-32-10.2.0.2-20060428.zip
- instantclient-sqlplus-hpux-ia64-32-10.2.0.2-20060428.zip

Created a symbolic link for some missing libraries:

- cd /apps/oracle/instantclient_10_2
- ln -s libclntsh.so.10.1 libclntsh.so

Then set the Library search path

- $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/oracle/instantclient_10_2
- $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

And now I am stuck, I know a tnsnames.ora file is needed but do not know where to place it (or if I should also have a sqlnet.ora file).

When I try executing sqlplus I get the following:

> sqlplus
>   bash: /apps/oracle/instantclient_10_2/sqlplus: Invalid argument

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to install on Solaris or HP-UX?  Your message says "Solaris x86-64" but your files list mentions *-hpux-ia64-* - different OS, different architecture.  There's no way it'll work.  If you're installing on Solaris, you need to download the appropriate (different) binaries from oracle.com.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't download the files so I just assumed they were the right ones... however, by talking to my co-worker he told me he accidentally downloaded these because he was looking for version 10.2.0.2 but that wasn't available at http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/sol64soft.html and ended finding the correct version (but not for the correct OS).

We'll try it right now, wondering if they're is a difference between 10.2.0.2 and 10.2.0.4 ?

Comment: There's not much difference between minor revisions in a release, mostly bug fixes. It's not important that client versions match the RDBMS, either. We still have version 8 client software hitting our 10g databases.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the obvious ;-)